# Exact way of ignore/unignore files in git

Tags: git

In my project I have a gitignore file, that nicely has statement to ignore node_modules, such as:

```
########################
# node.js / npm
########################
lib-cov
*.seed
*.log
*.csv
*.dat
*.out
*.pid
*.gz


logs
results

node_modules
```

It works just as expected. Git does not see any change within node_modules.

I have changes in a file within node_modules that I would like to include in further commits, as it will change definitely. But at the same time I want to keep the rest of the node_modules ignored.
This is example of what I need to "unignore":

```
 node_module/passport-saml/saml.js
```

Some time ago, I had the same issue. I have followed some instructions how to do it, but I ended up creating a mess... I remember I used git uncheck / untrack or something similar. It took me more time to fix the thing I broke while trying to "unignore" the file. At the end, I ended up manually changing the line of code on the git.

This time I really would like to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't have to add any special exception, *git* already handles that, once the file has been added once.

To add a file that fits a filter in your `.gitignore`, just force it by adding the `-f` param:

```
git add -f node_module/passport-saml/saml.js
```

Once the file is added, it will be tracked like any other file, even though the ignore filter matches.

Just change it and then add it as usual:

```
git add node_module/passport-saml/saml.js
```

That's it. No need for any special rules or exceptions.

Comment: `git add --force` instead of an unignore pattern will cause problems if the file or directory moves around. See [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723384/2223505)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `!` before path in your .gitignore file to invert the pattern:

```
 !node_module/passport-saml/saml.js
```

From [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again

Comment: @Wexoni Sure. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820255/how-do-negated-patterns-work-in-gitignore/2820310#2820310) out

Comment: I totally see me using this :). Thanks for this tip.

Comment: This is the correct solution, [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723384/2223505)

Answer (score 6):

You can add that file, and start tracking it with the `--force` option:

```
git add --force node_module/passport-saml/saml.js
```

From [`git add` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

```
-f
--force
```

> Allow adding otherwise ignored files.