# Potential pitfalls of Git --force and modified index for integrating Jekyll and Heroku w/ a Bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket, jekyll, bitbucket-pipelines

**Task:** I want to use a Bitbucket pipeline to deploy a Jekyll site to Heroku without adding the `_site` folder generated by local Jekyll builds.

**Possible Solution:** Below are my pipeline commands for building a Jekyll `_site` folder in the Docker container, modifying the git index, and pushing to Heroku. The build passes and deploys correctly to Heroku.

```
script:
  - bundle install --path vendor/bundle
  - npm install -g gulp
  - gulp preview
  - git config --global user.email $EMAIL
  - git config --global user.name $USER
  - git rm . -r --cached
  - git add -f Procfile index.js _site package.json
  - git commit -m "Eliminate all but site"
  - git push -f https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

**Remaining Concerns:** I'm removing all of the files from the index except for the files that Heroku needs to deploy. I'm also forcing `git add` and `git push` which are generally discouraged ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723384/8585320), [2](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/)). Fyi, `git push --force-with-lease` fails w/ `! [rejected]        HEAD -> master (stale info)`

I've been working on this for a few days and haven't found any references to the above uses of `git --force` commands with Bitbucket pipelines and Heroku. But since Bitbucket pipeline commands are performed within a [Docker container with a cloned repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html), the idiosyncratic usage shouldn't matter, right? It's okay to `git --force` changes bc these changes are entirely separate from local copies and the Bitbucket repo. The usual concerns about overwriting local changes and history w/ force don't apply.

I've only been working with Bitbucket pipelines, Jekyll, and Docker for a few weeks, so I just want to make sure I'm covering my bases. Thanks for any help!