# .gitignore unignore wildcard subdirectory

Tags: git, qt, gitignore

Using QtCreator I have the following in my `.gitignore`

```
*build-*
```

This lets me ignore everything inside the buildfolder, which depending on platform and build tools can have different names starting with `build-`.

Now I would like to unignore subdirectories inside this folder, such as `images` and `backup` and I assummed all I had to do was

```
!build-*/**/
```

But this has no effect, `git status` doesn't pick up any of the files in the subdirectories of `build-*`.

What am I  missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261959/unignore-subdirectories-of-ignored-directories-in-git

Comment: This is a rather bad idea. You're supposed to delete those build folders at any time, or have very many of them. You're doing something weird - perhaps you should explain why you want build products under source control?

Comment: If you have anything I can read up on to make testing of builds easier across multiple machines and users I welcome it, this is what I know for now. The application has to create folders and files    that need to persist between different builds.

Comment: @arynaq Yes, but if those intermediate files are a direct function of source code files, I could argue that you should not be versioning them.

Comment: Further to that, you shouldn't mix and match those two types of files (source and build output) in the same directory.  Keep them separate.  Everything that is created as part of the build output should be in a separate folder, and since it's generated by the build, never has to be (and never should be) checked in.