# Include generally excluded file from specific folder

Tags: git, gitignore

In my project, I have generated files Widget.js in project subfolders, so I git-ignore them with this rule:

```
widgets/*/Widget.js
```

so it ignores files like:

- widgets/ignore_1/Widget.js
- widgets/ignore_2/Widget.js

But now, in one specific folder, I want to include this file to repository. E.g.: file

- widgets/include_1/Widget.js

should be included.

Is there any possibility to set the rules as I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ! to add this file again https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format.

Just add

```
!widgets/include_1/Widget.js
```

after

```
 widgets/*/Widget.js
```

Answer (score 0):

First unignore the direcory and then the file in your .gitignore:

```
widgets/*/Widget.js
!widgets/include_1/
!widgets/include_1/Widget.js
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285539/7976758

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the single file, it might be easier to just force add the file and not touch the `.gitignore` rules at all. `.gitignore` only works on untracked files, so once you add the file once, it will remain tracked:

```
git add -f widgets/include_1/Widget.js
```

[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--f):

> **-f**
>
> **--force**
>
> Allow adding otherwise ignored files.