# how to make change in GitIgnore listed file?

Tags: git, github

I have to make any change in a file which is listed in .gitignore(in vendor/assets/bower_compenents).
How can I commit it. (Since I dont find a tracking history of the file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force add despite the .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006393/force-add-despite-the-gitignore-file)

Comment: There are a few great suggestions. The link evolutionxbox provides is solid. And I suggest the answer provided by user A-S. That answer links to a great explanation of approaches that work and why they work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261959/unignore-subdirectories-of-ignored-directories-in-git